# Data shape and specifying model in mlogit for R

Tags: r, multinomial, mlogit

I am trying to use the mlogit package in R to do some analyses. Unfortunately, I am a bit confused by how to specify the appropriate model given the type of data I have.

Specifically, my data are of the following type:

```
Individual   Choice1  Choice2   Choice3 ...
A             1.24e4      256        17 ...
B                792      531       420 ...
C                 26    1.8e5       930 ...
...              ...      ...       ... ...
```

Essentially a cross-table showing how many times each individual made a particular choice. Here is code to reproduce my issue:

```
library(mlogit)
data(Fishing)
otherFrame <- as.data.frame(xtabs(rep(1,1182) ~ income + mode, data = Fishing))
otherFrame$income <- as.numeric(as.character(otherFrame$income))
otherFrame <- otherFrame[otherFrame$Freq > 0, ] 


Fish <- mlogit.data(Fishing, varying = c(2:9), shape = "wide", choice = "mode")
Fish2 <- mlogit.data(otherFrame, "mode", shape = "wide")

summary(mlogit(mode ~ 1 | income, data = Fish)) #model from mlogit examples
summary(mlogit(mode ~ 1 |income, data = Fish2, weights = Freq)) #my attempt to re-create the model with differently shaped data
```

Basically, my data (not shown) can be put in the same shape as `otherFrame` and but there is no way for me to put them into the shape used in the `mlogit` examples (because there are hundreds of choices and millions of observations, thus the size is prohibitive). The key to `otherFrame` is the `Freq` column which shows the number of times a choice (`mode`) was made given some other variables (here `income`).

The issue I have is that the last two lines of code produce different results. I assume the first line (which comes directly from `mlogit` examples) gives the correct estimates and standard errors.  I thought the second model specification, with my alternative data “Fish2” where I specify `weights = Freq`, should give the same results. Unfortunately, while the estimated slopes are the same, their standard errors are vastly different. I assume this is incorrect.

Can someone help me specify the model correctly? Or perhaps my specification is correct an the standard error of the estimates should be different?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the `weights` argument doesn't represent case weights which are commonly developed for survey observations. It, however, corrects the aggregate market shares or the `Frequencies of alternatives`  and that's why you get the same estimates.

`mlogit` treats `otherFrame` as if it contains data of 57 records (i.e. `length(weights)` not `sum(weights)`) when in fact it contains data for 1182 records. In other words,  the information is lost by aggregating the data without including case weights - which explains the higher standard errors. Take a look at the `vcov` matrix of both fitted models.

Multiplying the t-stats of the 2nd model by `sqrt(sum(weights)`/`length(weights))` gets you a closer estimate of the correct t-stats. Note that also the loglikelihood in the 2nd model (and therefore the rho-squared value) is not going to be correct for the same reasons.

Other commercial software like Stata and alogit have routines to factor in case weights for discrete choice models.

Hope that helps!

Comment: yes! I did actually notice this yesterday after posting (i.e. that the number of records was being treated as 57 instead of 1182). Do you happen to know the routines names in Stata that factor in case weights? R might have something similar that I could dig up.

Comment: Check: https://www.stata.com/manuals13/rmlogit.pdf 
"fweights, iweights, and pweights are allowed; see [U] 11.1.6 weight"